# Is there any way to merge the multivalue indexes in a list using xsl templates?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml as below.

```
<tns:narrative2List>
    <tns:narrative2 index="1">John Doe</tns:narrative2>
    <tns:narrative2 index="2">Badi Salah</tns:narrative2>
    <tns:narrative2 index="3">Gabriel Jok Riak</tns:narrative2>
</tns:narrative2List>
```

I need to merge tns:narrative2 names ad my output should be as "John Doe Badi Salah Gabriel jok Riak"

using xsl templates.

I am new to xslt programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Code
<xsl:template match="/tns:Flow1/tns:narrative2List">
<narrative>
<xsl:for-each select="//tns:narrative2">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</narrative>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: <xsl:template match="/tns:Flow1/tns:narrative2List/tns:narrative2">
 <narrative>
         <xsl:for-each select="/tns:Flow1/tns:narrative2List/tns:narrative2">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
    </narrative>
    </xsl:template> 
This gives me output as below
<narrative2List>
            <narrative>John Doe Badi Salah Gabriel Jok Riak </narrative>
            <narrative>John Doe Badi Salah Gabriel Jok Riak </narrative>
            <narrative>John Doe Badi Salah Gabriel Jok Riak </narrative>
         </narrative2List>

Comment: change <xsl:template match="/tns:Flow1/tns:narrative2List">

Comment: <xsl:template match="/tns:Flow1/tns:narrative2List">
<narrative>
<xsl:for-each select="//tns:narrative2">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</narrative>
</xsl:template>

Comment: @Bhar S It's ok